# Assigning elevation to reclassified raster in ArcScene or ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, elevation, 3d-analyst, arcscene

How it it possible to make a 3D view of reclassifed raster map in ArcScene or ArcMap?

I have identified a potenial avalanche area using DEM in ArcMap and now I want to have this map in a 3D view in ArcScene but i can't since it is reclassified from 1 to 4 means I don't know the elevation value in the areas but want to present it in 3D view.

I have attached the image of reclassed file.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Layer Properties of your Geomorphogical_FPA layer, Base Heights tab. Click the radio button 'Floating on custom surface'. Choose your DEM as the surface to drape the classified image on top of. You can also improve the display quality by adjusting the Quality enhancement for raster images on the Rendering tab.

Steps:

[image: Layer Properties]

Resulting reclassified raster draped on top of a dem. 
[image: In this example slope classes are draped on top of the DEM]